# Store parameter in a function

Tags: odoo

I have a relation between the fuel and voucher classes with the field 'amount_used' that calculates the number of voucher x used in fuel without problems

```
_name = 'fleet.vehicle.log.fuel'
'voucher_id': fields.many2one('fleet.voucher', 'Voucher'),

_name = 'fleet.voucher'
'amount_used': fields.function(_count_all, type='integer', string="Amount Used")

def _count_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):

    Fuel = self.pool['fleet.vehicle.log.fuel']
    return {
        voucher_id: Fuel.search_count(cr, uid, [('voucher_id', '=', voucher_id)], context=context)
for voucher_id in ids
    }
```

when I add the store parameter in 'amount_used' I have an update problem

```
store=True or store={'fleet.vehicle.log.fuel': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['voucher_id'], 10)}
```

Comment: @Mehndi Mokni please paste the proper code over hear your code is not sufficient to judge the proper decision of your question reviewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
store={'fleet.vehicle.log.fuel': (_get_voucher, ['voucher_id'], 10)}



def _get_voucher(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

res = []

for fuel in self.pool.get('fleet.vehicle.log.fuel').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):

if fuel.voucher_id:

res.append(fuel.voucher_id.id)

return res
```